# Не отображается QWidget, OglWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Начну с того, что в *.pro файле есть строки:

```
QT       += core gui opengl
LIBS     += -lglut -lglut32 -lopengl32 -lglu32
```

При вызове окна opengl все прекрасно работает. Но я хочу поместить виджет opengl в форму Qt. Сам виджет не отображается, но при передвижении окна видно, что оно чем-то нагружено, соответственно, сам виджет работает.

Comment: А если так   еще добавить QT += widgets

Comment: Есть greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets